# Alembic: how to downgrade an entire branch?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

Say this is my graph of alembic versions:

```
a -> b -> c -> d
       \> e -> f
```

i'm interested in rolling back `e` and `f` but not c and d

so the issue is:

1. `alembic downgrade` takes an argument that represents the target revision (rather than the revision to be rolled back)
2. `alembic downgrade e` will correctly downgrade from `f` to `e`
3. `alembic downgrade -1`, so far as I can tell, can technically roll back the head of either branch.
4. I can't seem to do `alembic downgrade b` to roll back `e` and `f` without also rolling back `c` and `d`

Is the thing I'm trying to do possible with `alembic`?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It turns out this has been an open issue since 2017.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/464

My solution, for posterity, is to make a new revision `g` that will undo the changes in `e` and `f` so I basically get to work from the state of `b`.